# Can reinstalling Android studio cause my Google Maps API not to display in my app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I created an app that utilizes Google Maps API, I always back up my app by saving copies of it on an external drive.

I recently reinstalled windows and had to reinstall Android Studio. When I import my app project that I saved and run it, I notice the Google Map doesn't display any geographical imagery. All I can see is the "Google" logo.

Do I have to recreate my project and copy over my java and XML layout files and try running it again to make it work?

I would just like to know what are the possible things that might can solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your development key (debug certificate) has changed and you will need let Google know your new one.

When you reinstalled Android Studio it created a new debug certificate for you.

When you reran your app it signed it with this new debug certificate and Google Maps is still expecting the old one.

You will need to change it to the new one in the Google Developer Console.

Follow the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: i have the same problem , i install android studio on new laptop, i have many project, is the new debug certificate can make more damage?

Comment: No damage, just a bit inconvenient. You either need to reuse the same key (difficult if you've reformatted/reinstalled and don't have backup) or update the valid keys with google

Comment: i will have inconvenient only with debug or with release versions too?(i have all signed keys)

Comment: If you sign everything with release keys you won't have this issue